# Length of string array via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to know the length of a string array - *without having an object instance* - via reflection?
E.g. in this case: 2.

```
public string[] Key
        {
            get { return new string[] { Name, Type }; }
        }
```

EDIT: ok, I will not try to do this, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well, when you access the `Key` property, you *DO* have an instance...?!

Comment: @mmix an array *never* changes size. Ever.

Comment: true, sorry for spam, permutated something in my brain

Comment: At which point you would like to know the length?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Of which array do you want to know the length if you don't have an instance of it?

Comment: Wait... perhaps you mean "reflect the Key property code, see that it's creating an Array and calc the size of the array that it will be created?".... I don't think you can do it (technically you could disassemble the methodbody and go through the IL, but I think it would be VERY difficult... Only with Lambda Expressions it's manageable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean "without having the exact type of the Array". C# Arrays all derive from `Array`, so you can cast an Array reference to `Array` and use the `Length` property.

If you TRULY wants to reflect the property,

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);
var prop = type.GetProperty("Key");
var method = prop.GetGetMethod();
var body = method.GetMethodBody();
var ils = body.GetILAsByteArray();
```

from here you'll have to use one of the various libraries to decode bytes to IL OpCodes (for example https://gist.github.com/104001) . The OpCode you are looking for is `newarr`. The last push of an int32 before the `newarr` is the size of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You have two things going on there... telling the length of an array is pretty simple once you have an array; you just call `.Length` (in the case of a vector).

However, you mention an instance, and you are showing an instance property; which makes me think it is the containing object you lack. In which case... no. You can't make a virtcall on a null instance. And trying to use static-call on an instance member of a class is very evil; IIRC the runtime will kick you for this.

You could, however, make it a static property just by adding the `static` modifier. Then you just pass in `null` as the instance to reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean you want to know the size of the array the property will return if it were called?

I don't think you can do it sensibly.

If the property had a conditional then it could return different sized arrays, so 
you'd have to evaluate the property to know the size. Which could have side effects or be dependent on other values in the object (or statics).

Consider this one:-

```
static public int n;

public string[] Key
{
  get {
    if (n > 1)
      return new string[] { "Name", "Type" };
    else
      return new string[] { "Name", "Type", "Cheese" };
  }
}
```

Basically, you'd have to run the code.